# Data structure for a with complex node

Tags: data-structures, graph

I have a directed-graph, each node is a complex data type.

Does anyone know How to build a data structure for this graph.
Like for the instance, picture here :

[image]

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the image, it just looks like a directed graph. I assume what you mean by "complex data type" is that each vertex holds some sort of complex information, such as a hash table or something.

What I recommend you do if to create a dedicated Vertex class that holds the relevant information, then create a graph class using either an adjacency matrix or adjacency list implementation, depending on how dense/sparse/big/small the graph will be.

Comment: I try to use adjacency matrix for this graph but I get some problems:

Comment: What sort of problems are you getting?

Comment: I try to use adjacency matrix for this graph, but: (1) I cannot present the relation between some nodes like c11, c21, c22... (2) each node will get some values after doing some algorithm's steps, they are not the same data type.